FirebaseAuth cannot catch "user-not-found" and "wrong-password" errors
So I created a simple registration cum login for an app using firebase, and I wrote this code for error handling.
 switch(e.code) 
                    {
                      case "invalid-email":
                        await showErrorDialog(context,"The entered e-mail format is invalid");// The email id is not in email format
                        break;
                      case "user-not-found":
                        await showErrorDialog(context,"The user is not registered");// The user is a new user/not already registered
                        break;
                      case "wrong-password":
                        await showErrorDialog(context,"wrong password"); // The entered password is wrong
                        break;
                      case "invalid-credential":
                        await showErrorDialog(context,"Invalid username-password combination. Try checking again and enter valid username password info"); // If the entered pair is not available
                        break;                       
                      default:
                        devtools.log("No errors");                     
                    }              

In  the above code, showErrorDialog() is a method to show warning to user, you can replace it with print/log statements.
My problem is, lets say I register a user abc@gmail.com with password "xyz456". Now I am able to login into this app with this credential correctly.
Now if I try to login with a unregistered email, lets say "fhhg@gmail.com", I am supposed to get user-not-found error, instead, I am getting "invalid-credential" error. Similarly, if I enter the user email correct with a wrong password, I am catching "invalid-credential" error instead of wrong password.
But if I enter the email format as wrong, like "grggvjhj" as email id, I CORRECTLY CATCH the "invalid-email" error.
TLDR:
invalid-email error is working
user-not-found and wrong-password aren't working. Instead I get to the "invalid-credential" error code.
I tried using trim() and toString() formatters in textediting controllers as well as in the Variables that I use to hold the email-password values.
I also tried to print the entire error, e.code and e.message, and it's clear all errors are considered "Invalid-credential" error by default.
There was a similar issue to another user but his issue is quite different, nonetheless I tried that solution as well and it didn't work for me. I am linking that issue here.
Flutter Firebase Auth reurn wrong errror message
Thanks in advance for your help!

It sounds like protection against email enumeration attacks is turned on on your project, which is the default for all projects created after September 15, 2023. With that protection on, it is no longer possible to distinguish between user-not-found and wrong-password as that is a security risk.
You will either have to have a more generic flow for all forms of invalid credentials, or you'll have to turn off the protection against email enumeration attacks on your project. Also see I Don't get Error codes of Firebase Auth in my Flutter App (I ONLY get INVALID_LOGIN_CREDENTIALS)
